# Auto switching between wired and wireless connections

Tags: wifi, local-area-network, wired, connections, switch

How about this situation. Our business deals a lot with medical information. And some of our clients have demands based off HIPPA, etc.
There is one now where they do not want an employee to have both wired and wireless on at same time. If the wireless is on the wired needs to be turned off automatically and vice versa. However, this can not be up to the end user to manage! 
I have looked for third party applications and only have found http://www.wirelessautoswitch.com   Does anyone know of anything else that is out there? Or possible something that can be done via group policy, etc.?

Comment: Scary.  If it were me, I'd probably ban wireless networking completely.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what's the motivation behind this behavior?